# IE8 + window.history hack not working (Using History.js)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, history.js

I'm using History.js trying to resolve the lack of compatibility of window.history.pushState on IE8 and IE9.

I encapsulated all hack's functions in a hacks.js file and made this function to resolve the pushState problem:

```
 window.history = {
    pushState: function(state, title, url){
      return History.pushState(state, title, url)
    }
 };
```

But IE8 fires a javascript error telling me that window.history (on char 3) is a not found member.

This is confusing because other hack function works properly:

```
  window.console = {log:function(){}};
```

Comment: I don't know if marking this as a duplicate of a newer question makes sense, but your question has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139571/hack-to-keep-history-pushstate-ie8-9