# Hack to keep history.pushState ie8-9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

On most modern browsers, I'm able to use:

```
history.pushState({}, 'Our Work','/url/path/');
```

Obviously IE doesn't support this, but I'm wondering why my simple hack doesn't work?

```
history = {
    pushState : function(state,title,url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
};
```

I've also tried:

```
window.history = {
    pushState : function(state,title,url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
};
```

But I get a 'member not found' attribute.

Is this even possible with IE8?

I really didn't want to include a whole library for this simple hack, it's weird though because adding:

```
if (!window.console) {
    console = {
        log: function() {},
        error: function() {}
    };
}
```

Fixes my console logs...

Any help would be great!

Comment: I see no reason why it won't work. Hmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the history object does exist and it cannot be completely replaced.

But you can add additional methods to it

so setting

```
history.pushState = function(state,title,url){alert(url);};
```

will do the trick.